# git alias for shell command to cd into git root not working as expected

Tags: git, shell, alias

I'm trying to define an alias to `cd` me into the git root directory using `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.

Currently I have it as an alias in my `.bashrc`, which works fine:

```
alias gitroot='cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"'
```

But I know that you can run shell commands using git aliases, so I thought I'd move the command into my `.gitconfig` to make my files a bit cleaner.

Problem is, I can't figure out why my alias isn't working. Currently I have this under `[alias]` in my `.gitconfig`:

```
root = "!sh -c 'cd \"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)\"'"
```

But when I run `git root`, I just stay put in the current directory.

I've experimented with other shell aliases and they've worked, e.g. the alias `say = "!sh -c 'echo \"$0\"'"` works just fine:

```
$ git say hello
hello
```

Though I've noticed that a similar `cd` command (`cd = "!sh -c 'cd \"$0\"'"`) fails:

```
~/repos/myproject$ git cd /home/
~/repos/myproject$
```

I can't figure out if it's something to do with my syntax or if it's a quirk of git aliases that it doesn't support the `cd` command, or something else entirely.

If it helps, I'm using Git 1.7.9.5.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your shell is invoking Git, and Git is invoking another shell in which to run your `cd` command.  This command is successful, and this changes the working directory of the child shell, but it does not change the working directory of Git, nor of the parent shell.

In order to do this you need to run the command in your *current* shell, which means that **invoking Git will not be able to accomplish this.  You will have to continue using a shell alias.**

---

To illustrate, let's say you have the following shell script called `up.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ..
```

If you execute this script as `./up.sh` then nothing will change from the perspective of your current shell, because `cd` was executed in a new shell instance.  However, if you execute it as `. up.sh`, this instructs your current shell to execute the contents of the file by itself, without spawning a subshell.  In that case the current shell's working directory will change.

That's the key difference here.  Using a Git alias is similar to the `./up.sh` method, while a shell alias is similar to the `. up.sh` method.

Comment: Awesome, that explains it perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @cdhowie [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032476/96588), you can't do this from within an actual Git alias. But you *can* achieve this in a way that's almost indistinguishable to a Git alias, using a [wrapper function](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/commit/d7987c1a6571a6ad2e430ed62459abac85e60525):

```
git() {
    if [[ "$*" == 'root' ]]; then
        local root
        root="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" || return $?
        cd "$root" || return $?
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

Features, aside from the obvious of going to the root of the Git repo in `PWD`:

- Using a `local` variable avoids polluting the namespace.
- Does the right thing in a couple of corner cases:

  - Returns the `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` exit code if that command fails (typically because you're not in a Git repo).
  - Returns the `cd` exit code if for some reason `cd`ing to the root directory fails.
  - Shows the standard error output of the above commands if any of them fail, for debugging purposes.
- Forwards any command other than `git root` to the `git` command itself.