# Using Git aliasing for changing directory in Windows CMD

Tags: git, cd, git-alias

This is arguably a convoluted question, but **is there a way to create a Git command to change directory using aliasing, but to be used in the Windows command prompt?**

The goal is to leverage Git's straightforward aliasing functionality and avoid more complex solutions native to cmd, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54866820/5767535).

To illustrate, the below shows what I am trying to do:

```
> git config --system alias.foo "cd <long_directory_name>"
> cd
<some_directory>
> git foo
> cd
<long_directory_name>
```

Of course the above fails because `cd` is not recognized as a Git command.

Comment: What you're asking was possible in DOS, a single-process OS with one global current directory. It's impossible in any multi-process OS including Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032476/7976758 for an explanation. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alias+cd